# Generate a CSS file like Google Fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, google-font-api, dynamic-css

I have been using webfonts on my website for a while. (My website is using WordPress.)

I'm quite interested in using WOFF2 because of better compression. Currently, I'm using Noto Sans Japanese (via Google Fonts) for Japanese text.

However, I prefer the font [M+ C Type-2](http://mplus-fonts.sourceforge.jp/mplus-outline-fonts/design/index-en.html) as its Japanese glyphs look much better on small sizes (16px). I have added font hinting and converted the font above into WOFF2 and WOFF successfully.

Then I find out that Google Fonts API [serves a different CSS file for each browser](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/technical_considerations.html#Serving).

I'm uploading the fonts I want to Google Drive and I want to serve them via such dynamic CSS like that. How should I do?

Comment: Here is the tool: https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-ranger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that you will need server-side code, but as you are using Google Drive you may want to add more font extensions so each browser uses the right one.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Use [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) font generator, it's so popular.

Comment: I'm not sure that this approach would load all font files in the file or not. Also, FontSquirrel doesn't have the Japanese option, so I have to enter the unicode ranges for the Japanese glyphs manually. But when I do that, the generator freezes or doesn't show a preview of the characters in the ranges I put in.

Comment: @LQ2' Browser only downloads one font from the list. I'm sorry about that, send them an email they may help you.